# Java library for creating Audio CD disk image

Tags: java, audio, diskimage, cdda

Does anyone know of a library or open source project that contains code for creating an audio CD disk image?

Answer (score 1):

As this is a rather technical task you may want to use the Java Native Interface (JNI).